# How to align two sets of timestamps

Tags: python, timestamp

This was a tricky question to name. Here is what I am trying to do:
I have two sets of timestamps. I name the first one `t_x` and the second one `t_y`. For one `t_x` there are several corresponding `t_y`'s.

For example, take `t_x = [1,4,6]` and we have `t_y[1] = [1,3,7]`, `t_y[4] = [2,4,6]` and `t_y[6] = [5,6,7]`.

This could be plotted in a `(t_x, t_y)` graph.
Now I am taking the set of slopes, which is `(t_y1 - t_y2)/(t_x1 - t_x2)`, for `t_x1` "close" to `t_x2` and `t_y1` "close" to `t_y2`.

The question here is the following: what would be the most time-efficient way to process the slopes? Is there a good data structure to hold the timestamps in order to speed up the calculation?

I am using mostly python by the way, but I can read most common languages.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: what is t_y1, t_y2 and so on, I don't see it anywhere defined... (consider pasting formulas as LaTeX image, [e.g. via WYSIWYG editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php?lang=en-us)). Probably it is clear to people who are familiar with this kind of problem, which I am not.

Comment: In that case let's rephrase the problem. You have a lot of point `(x,y)` that are scattered accross [0, tmax]x[0,tmax].
You want to compute all the "relevant" slopes of the segments between pairs of points. "relevant" here means that in each segments, the two end points are not too far from each other.
How to do that efficiently?

Comment: the naming is confusing `t_y` is not like `t_x`. You could call them `x` and `ys` instead where `x = data.keys()`, ys = data.values()`, and `data = {1: [1, 3, 7],  4: [2, 4, 6], 6: [5, 6, 7]}`. What are `t_y1`, `t_x1`? btw, I don't see any connection between your question and your last comment: it sounds like different problems. Provide example input/expected output. Provide perhaps very inefficient but **correct** example implementation. How many points are there? Don't put a necessary info in the comment, [edit] your question instead.